# Custom cumulative expression on rows in polars

Tags: python-polars

I would like to calculate time-aware exponential moving average, unfortunately polars doesn't have one.

Well, it shouldn't be hard to do it by hand, should it?

Let's define the terms:

**x<sub>i</sub>**: values

**t<sub>i</sub>**: times

**y<sub>i</sub>**: resulting exponential moving average

Then it's quite easy to calculate the *y* recursively using following formulas:

*Δt<sub>i+1</sub> = t<sub>i+1</sub> − t<sub>i</sub>*

*q<sub>i+1</sub> = exp(-Δt<sub>i+1</sub>/λ)*

y<sub>0</sub> = x<sub>0</sub>

*y<sub>i+1</sub> = q<sub>i+1</sub> × y<sub>i</sub> + (1 − q<sub>i+1</sub>) × x<sub>i+1</sub>*

I can easily see how to calculate a column of *Δt*s using shifts, deriving a column of *q*s is also trivial.

However, I am struggling how to express the last recursive relationship. Is there a way to make a `polars.Expr` that would define a column calculated recursively?

Surely, I can write all of this in `numba`, but I wouldn't want to loose the lazy streaming ability of `polars`, nor do I want to compromise on speed.

Comment: I don't think there's a lazy / speedy way to calculate one value at a time in a column. Thus, there's no expression yet for recursive operations like this.

Comment: What is λ supposed to be in the denominator of qi+1

Comment: @DeanMacGregor λ is a constant here denoting a typical decay time. It's conceptually similar to halftime, actually halftime = λ * ln(2)

Comment: is it "halflife", rather than "halftime"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `polars-xdt`

I think the formula you've given is for the unadjusted EWMA, so make sure to pass `adjust=False` to get results which match your formula

example:

```py
In [2]: import polars as pl
   ...: import polars_xdt as xdt
   ...: from datetime import date, timedelta
   ...: df = pl.DataFrame(
   ...:     {
   ...:         "values": [0, 1, 2, None, 4],
   ...:         "times": [
   ...:             date(2020, 1, 1),
   ...:             date(2020, 1, 3),
   ...:             date(2020, 1, 10),
   ...:             date(2020, 1, 15),
   ...:             date(2020, 1, 17),
   ...:         ],
   ...:     }
   ...: )
   ...: df.with_columns(
   ...:     ewma=xdt.ewma_by_time(
   ...:         "values", times="times", halflife=timedelta(days=4), adjust=False,
   ...:     ),
   ...: )
Out[2]:
shape: (5, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬──────────┐
│ values ┆ times      ┆ ewma     │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---      │
│ i64    ┆ date       ┆ f64      │
╞════════╪════════════╪══════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 2020-01-01 ┆ 0.0      │
│ 1      ┆ 2020-01-03 ┆ 0.292893 │
│ 2      ┆ 2020-01-10 ┆ 1.492474 │
│ null   ┆ 2020-01-15 ┆ null     │
│ 4      ┆ 2020-01-17 ┆ 3.254508 │
└────────┴────────────┴──────────┘
```

Note that, for now, you'll need the `polars-xdt` plugin for this to work

Comment: Cool stuff, thanks!

Just one note, I believe that the adjusted EWMA by_time is a fundamentally flawed concept. I was already raising that in pandas github in the past:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/54328

Comment: thanks! should I remove `adjust=True` then, or simply default to `adjust=False` here?

Comment: Well, I would simply remove `adjust=True` completely. There might be a way to do the adjusting properly, but this is not it and I would have to think about that more deeply to figure out what the correct approach would look like.

Comment: thanks! yeah I've removed `adjust` completely from `polars-xdt`, if I manage to upstream this to Polars then I'll leave `adjust` out for now, and it'll just use the recursive (unadjusted) formula