# How to apply polars.Expr.map to multiple series?

Tags: python-polars

According to docs, one can use `polars.Expr.map` to *Apply a custom python function to a Series or sequence of Series.*

Accordingly the function signature shows:

```
def map(
        self,
        function: Callable[[Series], Series | Any],
        return_dtype: PolarsDataType | None = None,
        *,
        agg_list: bool = False,
    ) -> Self:
```

Yet, I didn't manage to figure out calling it in a way that would actually pass more than a single serie at the time.

I am trying to implement my own version of `rolling_mean` and I would need to be able to pass values and weights simultaneously.

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty answer is [`pl.map`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.map.html).

```py
polars.map(
    exprs: Sequence[str] | Sequence[Expr],
    function: Callable[[Sequence[Series]], Series],
    return_dtype: PolarsDataType | None = None,
) -> Expr[source]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can "group" multiple columns/expressions together with [`pl.struct()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.struct.html#polars.struct)

Inside your function you can use the [Series.struct.*](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/series/struct.html) accessors:

```
def my_function(s):
   print(s)
   print("---")
   print(s.struct["foo"])
   print("---")
   print(s.struct["baz"])
      
df = pl.DataFrame({"foo": [1, 2, 3], "bar": [4, 5, 6], "baz": [7, 8, 9]})

df.with_columns(pl.struct("foo", "baz").map_elements(my_function))
```

```
shape: (3,)
Series: 'foo' [struct[2]]
[
    {1,7}
    {2,8}
    {3,9}
]
---
shape: (3,)
Series: 'foo' [i64]
[
    1
    2
    3
]
---
shape: (3,)
Series: 'baz' [i64]
[
    7
    8
    9
]
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to do this as extension on polar expr?

What I am trying to achieve is to simulate the existing api of rolling_mean, so something like this:

pl.col("my_col").my_extension.rolling_mean(window_size=2.0, by='x', weights='y')

Comment: Well, `pl.struct()` returns an `Expr` so `pl.struct(...).my_extension` should pass the struct into your function.

Comment: Well, I would like to push the struct part inside the extension to make the code transparent for the user.

Comment: You'd have 2 functions. You'd have 1 function which is written with all python objects using numba if you like. You'd have a second function which would call the first function with polars expressions in mind via struct and map. The second function is the one you'd put in the `polars.Expr.my_extension` namespace

Comment: Are you using `.map()` inside your custom function? `pl.col(kwargs['weights'])` inside your function gives you `pl.col('y')` - It's probably worth editing your question to include the API extension specific stuff as I think this answer may be irrelevant to what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

From your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76886343/custom-cumulative-expression-on-rows-in-polars)'s mention of numba, I see you're considering using that. If you use numba to create a [uFunc](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/expressions/numpy/) then you can skip map altogether as polars accepts uFuncs directly.

Say you make a trivial function that just adds to numbers rowwise

```
@numba.guvectorize([(numba.float64[:], numba.float64[:], numba.float64[:])], '(n),(n)->(n)')
def g(x,y, res):
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        res[i]=x[i]+y[i]
g([1,2,3], [5,3,1])
#array([6., 5., 4.])
```

Nothing earth shattering here but say you have a dataframe:

```
df=pl.DataFrame({'a':[1.1,2.3,3.3], 'b':[8.1,7.3,6.64]})
```

Since g is a numpy ufunc, you can do this directly without map

```
df.with_columns(z=g(pl.col('a'), pl.col('b')))
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b    ┆ z    │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1.1 ┆ 8.1  ┆ 9.2  │
│ 2.3 ┆ 7.3  ┆ 9.6  │
│ 3.3 ┆ 6.64 ┆ 9.94 │
└─────┴──────┴──────┘
```

But that doesn't look good because it's different from the rest of polars syntax. You can wrap that in your own expression and either register your own namespace or monkey patch it in.

```
def cust_func(self, other_col):
    return g(self, pl.col(other_col))
pl.Expr.cust_func=cust_func
```

Now you can do:

```
df.with_columns(c=pl.col('a').cust_func('b'))
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b    ┆ c    │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1.1 ┆ 8.1  ┆ 9.2  │
│ 2.3 ┆ 7.3  ┆ 9.6  │
│ 3.3 ┆ 6.64 ┆ 9.94 │
└─────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Of course the point of this exercise isn't to demonstrate how to replace `pl.col('a')+pl.col('b')` but to show that you can define `g` however you like (within numba constraints) and it'll become a ufunc which polars accepts directly and will be compiled which means fast. You can then just wrap that in a defined expression, monkey patch it into the Expr namespace, and then use it the same as any built in method.

Comment: This looks cool, thanks a lot!

One quick question though, any idea how to handle potential null (None) values?

Comment: I don't know if this is optimal but just mechanically you could do a fill_null with a very specific value that couldn't exist in real data and then inside the custom function's for loop check for that value and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Hm, unfortunately, it seems that this approach has some limitations. I can't seem to be able to provide a function with both expressions and non-expressions at the same time due to this error message:

 "Numpy ufunc with more than one expression can only be used if all non-expression inputs are provided as keyword arguments only"

However, it looks like numba doesn't support keyword arguments.